Sqlite is not loading in powershell
First of all, I installed the Visual Studio Code and then I got the sqlite files extracted to a folder in my C drive. In a folder called lectures, I have 6 zip files one of whichs is called src0.zip. This zip file contains a database file called longlist.db. I tried to execute the command for loading the longlist.db file using sqlite by using PS C:\lectures\src0> sqlite3 longlist.db
Here is the image which shows the error I encountered. It asks me how I want to open the database file instead of loading the sqlite3 command
I have also set the path for the sqlite binary using environmental variables settings but it still doesn't load the sqlite3. Just so you know, it works fine in my Windows cmd and Command Prompt in VS Code but it doesn't work in powershell. What should I do?
I was expecting it to load the sqlite showing me the message:

SQLite version 3.45.2 2024-03-12 11:06:23 (UTF-16 console I/O) Enter
".help" for usage hints

for the code: sqlite3 longlist.db
which confirms that sqlite has been invoked into the VS Code using powershell but instead, it showed me a message asking how I want to open the file as shown in the given image.
